# How to extract the nth line of a text file in Windows using cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bunch of text files from which I need to extract the 9th line and write it to a different file.

I know that I can iterate through the files in a specific directory with `for %%f in (*.txt) de ( )` and I know that I can append whatever I extract to a different file with `echo` but I have no idea of how to specifically extract the nth line of the current file (i.e. line 9).

Comment: Don't call the Windows cmd "DOS", [they're very different from each other](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also iterate over the output of a command (sequence):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir') do echo %%a
```

You just have a way to find the nth line, which is easy with the `/N` switch of `findstr`:

```
findstr /n "^" file.txt
```

(find each line that has a start (which every line has) and number them)

Filter it for the desired line:

```
findstr /n "^" file.txt |findstr /b "9:"
```

(filter each line that starts with `9:`)

and use a `for` loop to dissect the line number and actual line:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %a in ('findstr /n  "^" file.txt ^|findstr /b "9:"') do @echo %b
```

Use another `for` loop around to process several files:

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%%f" ^|findstr /b "9:"') do @echo %%b
)
```

and redirect the whole output to a new file:

```
@echo off
(for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%%f" ^|findstr /b "9:"') do @echo %%b
))>file.out
```

Note: if you name your output file `.txt`, it might be processed too by `for %%f in (*.txt)` (that's how `for %%f` works: get a file name from disk in each iteration).

If you want the output file to have the same extension, you need a different version for your outer loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b *.txt') do
```

which first builds a list of filenames and then iterates over this list, so files created during the process are ignored.